# Javascript: Interactive Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

So what I have done is a simple slideshow that loops three images.
What I need to do know is add some js code to get my buttons working. Unless it's not clear by the name, I want to press the previous button to go back one image and the next button to go to the next image.

Also I want to keep the code in seperate documents (one for html, one for css, one for js).

```
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "pics/image1.png"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "pics/image2.png"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "pics/image3.png"

var nr = 1;

function slideshow() {

    document.images.slideshow.src = eval("image" + nr + ".src");

if (nr < 3) nr++;

    else nr = 1;

    setTimeout("slideshow()", 3000);

}

var prev = document.querySelector(".prev");
var next = document.querySelector(".next");


slideshow();
```

Find the full code here: here: http://jsfiddle.net/n5HHz/1/ (The image files are broken ofc)

Very thankful for help!

Comment: Check these links: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/show3.shtml http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-slideshow-in-javascript-for-beginners/28045

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/n5HHz/10/

Still not perfect, but maybe it'll give you a little help on how you can do it with onclick methods.

Also it starts automatic now, and jquery is added.

> $(document).ready(function() {
>      slideshow();
>   });

Images is is just random:

```
 var image1 = new Image()
 image1.src = "http://d1jqu7g1y74ds1.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/alma-580x580.jpg"
 var image2 = new Image()
 image2.src = "http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/bc85dff2b3dc44ddb9650e1659b1ad1e.png"
 var image3 = new Image()
 image3.src = "http://staticd.cdn.adblade.com/banners/images/100x75/4365_5229fd58bdf87.jpg"
```